# Java Higher Order Polymorphic Function

Tags: java, polymorphism, higher-order-functions

I am very familiar with functional langauges such as Scheme, and Haskell. I'm trying to solve a problem in Java and struggling, possibly because I'm still in a functional mindset.

I want to write:

```
public void doQueryAndStoreData(String query, <? extends Collection> storeIn) {
    /* make a jdbc query, get ResultSet */
    ResultSet rset = ...;
    ProcessResultSet proc = new ProcessResultSet();
    proc.process(rset, storeIn);
    /* clean up */
}
```

with an interface like:

```
private interface IProcessResultSet<C> {
    public void process(ResultSet rset, C storeIn);
}
```

and a class implementing the interface like:

```
private class ProcessResultSet implements IProcessResultSet<? extends Collection> {
    public void process(ResultSet rset, Map storeIn) {
        /* do something */
    }

    public void process(ResultSet rset, List storeIn) {
        /* do something else */
    }
}
```

so that the first method can call the appropriate `process` based on what type of `storeIn` it's given.

In Haskell I could write

```
class Storeable c a where
    store :: a -> c a -> c a

doQueryAndStoreData :: Storeable c a => ResultSet a -> c a -> c a
doQueryAndStoreData (ResultSet rs) coll = foldr store coll rs
```

and provide `Storeable` instances for whatever collection type I want to store my `ResultSet` in.

Is this the correct approach in Java? Because I feel like I'm somewhat fighting the langauge to accomplish this.

Comment: I think what you need can be solved using the visitor pattern - double dispatch.

Comment: Personally, I would be more apt to return something from a function. Tends to make the code more readable. Can't think of the closest supertype to Map and List, but that would be the return value, and then cast to Map/List in the assignment statement, i.e., `Map<something> myMap = new Map<something>; myMap = (Map<something>) process(rset, myMap);"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Java doesn't do that.

You'd need to do something like:

```
public <T> void doQueryAndStoreData(
    String query,
    T storeIn,
    ResultSetProcessor<T> processor
) {
```

Or much more likely:

```
public void doQueryAndStoreData(
    String query,
    ResultSetHandler handler // may contain processor and storeIn
) {
```

I hope I don't need to mention SQL injection vulnerabilities are a bad thing. (Also `Map` is not a `Collection` in Java (it is in C# but C# `Collection` isn't very useful).)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that, unfortunately. The compiler must know *at compile time* which method this call is bound to. If you want to decide which method to call **based on the runtime type** of the object, you have to manually check it:

The most you can do:

```
private class ProcessResultSet implements IProcessResultSet<? extends Collection> {

    @Override
    public void process(ResultSet rset, Collection storeIn) {
        if (storeIn instanceof Set) {
            return processSet(rset, (Set) storeIn);
        } else if (storeIn instanceof List) {
            return processList(rset, (List) storeIn);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unimplemented storage type");
        }
    }


    public void processSet(ResultSet rset, Set storeIn) {
        /* do something */
    }

    public void processList(ResultSet rset, List storeIn) {
        /* do something else */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private class ProcessResultSet implements IProcessResultSet<? extends Collection> {

    public void process(ResultSet rset, Object storeIn) 
    {
        if ( storeIn instanceof Map)
            processMap(rset,(Map) storeIn);
        else if (storeIn instanceof List)
            processList(rset,(List) storeIn);   
        else
            System.out.println("Unsupported input type.");
    }

    public void processMap(ResultSet rset, Map storeIn) {
        /* do something */
    }

    public void processList(ResultSet rset, List storeIn) {
        /* do something else */
    }
}
```